# Financial Options. fOptions vs RQuantLib

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

For some projects I am looking into financial options. I prefer to use `RQuantLib`, but sometimes its hard to convince others (Mac users for instance) to install `QuantLib`, `Boost`, etc. therefore I am also looking at the `fOptions`-package. However I have issues replicating results.

Mainly I am trying to calculate the price for American and European options, as well as the delta, gamma, vega, theta, and rho.

In `RQuantLib` everything works as expected:

```
library(RQuantLib)
EuropeanOption(type = "call", underlying = 100, strike = 100, dividendYield = 0, 
               riskFreeRate = 0.03, maturity = 1, volatility = 0.05)

# Concise summary of valuation for EuropeanOption 
# value    delta    gamma     vega    theta      rho   divRho 
# 3.7861   0.7340   0.0656  32.8161  -2.9089  69.6153 -73.4014
```

`fOptions` however gives me different results:

```
library(fOptions)
GBSOption(TypeFlag = "c", S = 100, X = 100, Time = 1, r = 0.03, b = 0, 
          sigma = 0.05)
# 
# Title:
#   Black Scholes Option Valuation 
# 
# Call:
#   GBSOption(TypeFlag = "c", S = 100, X = 100, Time = 1, r = 0.03, 
#             b = 0, sigma = 0.05)
# 
# Parameters:
#   Value:
#   TypeFlag c     
# S        100   
# X        100   
# Time     1     
# r        0.03  
# b        0     
# sigma    0.05  
# 
# Option Price:
#   1.935566 
# 
# Description:
#   Wed Nov  2 23:08:57 2016
```

Or similar for the greeks:

```
GBSGreeks(Selection = "delta", TypeFlag = "c", S = 100, X = 100, Time = 1, 
      r = 0.03, b = 0, sigma = 0.05)
# [1] 0.4949006
```

I am not necessarily bound to the `fOptions`-library, I just need a (rather) lightweight alternative to RQuantLib that doesn't need the installation of additional software (on Mac and Linux).

What am I missing? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose of the `b` argument to `fOptions::GBSOption`. It's not equivalent to the dividend yield in `RQuantLib::EuropeanOption`, it's actually the *cost of carry*. In your case with no dividend yield, the cost of carry is just the risk-free rate:

```
GBSOption(TypeFlag = "c", S = 100, X = 100, Time = 1, r = 0.03, 
          sigma = 0.05, b=0.03)

Title:
 Black Scholes Option Valuation 

Call:
 GBSOption(TypeFlag = "c", S = 100, X = 100, Time = 1, r = 0.03, 
           b = 0.03, sigma = 0.05)

Parameters:
          Value:
 TypeFlag c     
 S        100   
 X        100   
 Time     1     
 r        0.03  
 b        0.03  
 sigma    0.05  

Option Price:
 3.786116
```

This matches what you got from the other package.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Chris! For the interested reader that deals with dividendYields: in fOptions the cost of carry is equal to the risk-free rate minus the dividendYield...